# Windows 7 system image, undo external hard drive over written

Tags: windows-7, windows, images, restore

Every time I logged on to my laptop, I was pestered by Windows' image restore backup request, which I finally gave into.

I chose to save it to my external hard drive. When it finished, I found that it had overwritten all of my photos and memories from the last 50 years!

How on earth do I get it all back? Please help ASAP

Answer (score 1):

I want to recommend a handy tool for data restoration. It's free and fairly easy to use - personally I've used it couple of times and I was not disappointed. Click [here](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) for the software's webpage.

**With that being said**, I highly recommend taking the questioned hard drive to a certificated laboratory that specializes in data recovery in your area, since it contains data of high importance, especially for you.

Also, I must say that user with no expertise might cause additional damage to the data by using data recovery software incorrectly, by accident. It happens.

To recap, I suggest you consider paying for professional help in this matter if the files are very important to you. Otherwise, you can use data recovery software.

**Important note:** In the meantime, you mustn't use this hard drive because you may cause further data corruption, because when new files are written to the disk they might overwrite the data you wish to recover.

Comment: And some of those services will only make you pay if they *CAN* recover something

Answer (score 0):

If it formated your drive, it will be hard to recover it, but you could use data recovery software.
Here's link for a free data recovery program:
http://download.cnet.com/Data-Recovery/3000-2094_4-10664893.html